# What are the main C / C++ specifications

Tags: void

After there was a misunderstanding of "C/C++ programmers" with the a non-mentioned/existing "C/C++ language", and eventually getting the question closed, I decided to void it.

I had voted to delete it, and planned to split the question in two (C language specification, compilers and their version diffs, and C++ language specs, compilers and their version diffs), but it turns out a question with (ill formed) answers can't be deleted.

That was a big turn off for my SO experience... can't reformfulate a wrongly-closed ill-answered question... ouch.

Comment: It'd be simpler, and more accurate, to simply read the specification. There are more than enough C++ programmers out there already, following second-hand incomplete references.

Comment: yeah, this question is really non accurate. I mean the most voted non-answer is someone making a point on something that was not implied/written. And it will be better to have the C and C++ standards descriptions and related info be explained by mouth, or googling. By the way, by which merits is a wiki-flagged "what are the main c / c++ specification" not a valid programming question?

Answer (score 13):

There is no such thing as the "C/C++" language. The two have completely different language standards and differ in use in many, many ways. If you want to understand either C or C++ I suggest (and this is true for any language);

- read a book authored by one of the originators of the language. For C this would be Kernighan and Ritchie 2nd Ed, and for C++, Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language, 3rd Ed.
- when you are comfortable with the language, get  a copy of the language standard.

And can I also say that in all my time using the internet, I've never found an  online resource for C++ that could approach the quality of the available paper documentation.

Comment: +1 there's no such thing as C/C++

Comment: +1 Stroustrup said once there is C/C++ *community* but there is no such thing as C/C++ language.

Comment: I don't think the OP suggested there was a C/C++ language, and he did say "specifications" not "specification", so I don't think you are contradicting him.  The term C/C++ can legitimately refer to "both languages called C and C++", rather than "one language called C/C++).  Moreover C and C++ are share a common subset and ancestry and are therefore similar in as many as they are different.  There is a good reason why most if not all C++ compilers are also C compilers (and were often originally sold with "C/C++" written on the box and in the documentation).

Comment: You are assuming too much: I did not suggest a C/C++ language, but C/C++ programmers. I did program for 6 years in C++ and I do program C (embedded) on a regular basis. I do agree with you, and in fact, I was an avid reader of stroustrup's in my last year in college (for OO-prog class). Only after, by curiosity, I read K&R. I would challenge your immutable views on the quality of what can be done in the internet regarding C and C++ languages, but I'm sure you've made up your mind on that one.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia's articles on C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) have good references.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO C working group would be a good start: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/. But it's pretty hard to find anything on there.

Comment: Not a great place to start then eh?